# Laravel auth loses session after redirect

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Due to laravel's default auth system not working for my current project I used their [manual authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users). The authenticating works but after I redirect the authentication gets destroyed or it simply isn't getting stored properly.

My authController:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class manualAuthController extends Controller    {
    public function authenticate(){
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' => $_POST['password']])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            $user = Auth::user();
            //return '$user';
            return redirect("test2");
        }
        return 'Auth failed!';
    }
}
```

My route to test if the authenticated user is still stored:

```
Route::get('test2', function(){
    echo 'test2<br>';
    $user = Auth::user();
    echo $user;
    return '.';
});
```

If I uncomment "return '$user';" then the authenticated user gets returned properly.

I know that this question has been asked before but I couldn't find anybody with a working/ reliable solution to this problem so can someone here please help me with this problem(or finding the exact problem)?

Side note: I previously used the Socialite system which we had to switch for the laravel auth due to hosting problems. After this switch it worked in development for a while with my current session and db settings. Due to some other bugs I switched to manual authentication.

Comment: share your kernel file (kernel.php)